# The Fibrewise Multiplication on a Normal Vector Bundle of a subset of a Compact Kähler Surface

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be a (non-empty) subset of a compact kähler surface $\mathbb{X}$.

Denote by $\mathcal{N}(\mathbb{A})$ the normal vector bundle of $\mathbb{A}$.

What do they mean by saying "let $\varphi_{\lambda}$ be the fibrewise multiplication by $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$ on $\mathcal{N}(\mathbb{A})$"?

Comment: It should just be the usual multiplication of the fibres of a vector bundle. Each fibre has the structure of a complex vector space, so multiplication by some complex number is well-defined.